# Firebase remote config always return false for conditional keys iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am facing some issue while fetching keys and values from Remote Config. I am always getting false value for keys whichever has conditions. I tried to change build number and made minimumFetchingInterval = 0. But no luck.

I gone through the documentations but not found any solution. I also looked into these URLs but no luck.

[Firebase Remote Config App Version condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305778/firebase-remote-config-app-version-condition)
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3624

Please help me